# How to set size of prototype UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a UICollectionView in IB with a bunch of different prototype cells.

I have tried to give each cell its own size in IB so that when I instantiate it with dequeueReusable..., it will have that size. What I am finding however is that it doesn't matter what your settings in IB are for your cell, your collectionview uses its own cell size for all cells used inside it.

Is this a bug? If not what is the best way to set a custom size for all your cells?

I have also tried:

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSString* cellIdentifier = self.cellIdentifier;
    ImageCell* cell =  [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:self.cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    return [cell sizeOfCell];
}
```

But for some reason the app crashes when dequeuing cells in this function.

I have subclassed all the prototype cells and have a function that has them return their own size. Is there any other way to instantiate a cell with the Identifier you gave it in IB?

Answer (score 7):

The sizing of cells (for collection views and table views) in IB is just for layout purposes, it has no effect on the size at run time. You should implement the UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout method collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath: to return the correct size for each item.